Calibrating Cessna 172R fuel tanks
I am replacing our fuel sender units with new ones from CiES and need to calibrate how much fuel each tank can hold.  Each tank has a capacity of 28 gallons but only 26.5 gallons is usable.  The question is: Where do I drain the tank so I have a good "empty tank" to start from?  Do I just drain from the 5 wing sumps until they are dry?  Will this leave the 1.5 gallons of unusable fuel in the various nooks and crannies of the tank?  With an empty tank I should be able to add 26.5 gallons to fill it to the top.  But I need to set the starting point on my Aerospace Logic fuel gauge to either 0 gallons or 1.5 gallons.  Any advice on how to do this calibration properly?

You need to calibrate the sensors to what the engine considers empty, so empty for the purpose of the fuel gauge indication means the gauge must read empty with the unusable fuel in the tank (a savvy pilot who is in a fuel emergency, and is about to run dry, can get access to some of that unusable fuel by skidding, especially if the tank is long spanwise).
What I did when calibrating the dipstick I use to measure fuel quantity in my own airplane during preflight is drain the tanks via the gascolator so that unusable fuel remains in the tank.
So either do that, or deduct the published 1.5 gal unusable fuel from the measurement if you empty the tank by the tank's sump drain, which is supposed to remove everything. Make sure the wings are level.

Draining the fuel from the gascolator makes the most sense to me too.  That assumes there's 1.5 gallons X 2 tanks of unusable fuel somewhere in the fuel system.  That also means I should be able to 26.5 gallons to each tank to reach a "full" level reading on the fuel gauge.  I am starting at 1.5 gallons unusable on my gauge so between the usable and unusable fuel the gauge should read 28 gallons when I'm done.  I'll see what happens.

An A&P/IA I consulted said to just drain the tank from the lowest sump drain (our Cessna 172R has 5 drains per tank), add 1 1/2 gallons to represent unusable fuel and then add the 26 1/2 gallons of usable fuel for a total tank capacity of 28 gallons.  But I am coming up two gallons shy of this before the tank is full.  Maybe the 1 1/2 gallons of residual unusable fuel is already in the tank somewhere so I didn't need to add it myself?
All the Cessna procedures really don't address what an empty tank is once it has held fuel in it's lifetime.  Adding 1 1/2 gallons to a brand new empty tank could make sense.  But adding it to a tank that has held fuel and been drained may not.
Has anyone else tackled this problem before?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
